# How to debug "Unable to merge dex" in Java?

Tags: java, android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Comment: Hi, we require a bit more detail to be able to help you out. We gladly help people out, but this is not enough information. Please have a look at the faq [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Delete the .gradle directory, run the app again.

2.if still not working try this like below

Enable multiDexEnabled in .gradle file

```
defaultConfig { multiDexEnabled true }
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the top questions. I think the right option for you will be to run

```
./gradlew build --debug
```

And to watch carefully in the console. You will find something like BUILD FAILED, and you'll see the dependency that are called more than once around those lines.

Hope it helps.